# CMake Remove /arch:sse2 for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cmake

The project I'm working on right now uses CMake to generate an x64 visual studio 2010 project. Currently I'm in the process of converting it to x64 visual studio 2013.

Most everything has just fallen into place correctly, however I'm getting the following warning:

`cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/arch:SSE2'`

Tracking this issue down, it looks like visual studio 2013 no longer supports `/arch:SSE2` for x64 projects, as it is the default to use this extension.

I've searched through our various `CMakeLists.txt`'s (we've got on in each project, and one for the solution as a whole), and we're not setting the flag, so I'd assume that this is set by default in CMake.

In visual studio I can go to `project > properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Enable Enhanced Instruction Set` and set it to 'Not Set', and everything works without any warnings.

How can I do this from within the `CMakeLists.txt`?

I've seen several ways of setting variables, usually something along the lines of `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /arch:SSE2")`, but this can't be used to remove a flag (at least not that I'm aware of).

Comment: Wait, cmake shouldn't set this unless you do so in some of your included modules? Anyways, that flag just gets ignored by the compiler as it's the default for x64 anyways. Oh also do you use any other `/arch` flags?

Comment: Well, SSE2 is ALWAYS available on 64bit platform. This is actually a definition of minimum x86-64 platform: 16 64bit registers, SSE2 unit with 16 registers, RIP addressing, at least 40bit physical addressing etc. You'll get it whether you ask for it or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove this flag using [string manipulation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/string.html):

```
string(REPLACE "/arch:SSE2" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
```

If this doesn't work then try to use a temporary variable instead:

```
string(REPLACE "/arch:SSE2" "" OUT_VAR ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${OUT_VAR} CACHE)
```